# Evaluate linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{xy}{x^2-1}= \frac{x^4+2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Integration factor comes out to be $$\sqrt{x^2-1}$$ and then
$$y. \sqrt{x^2-1}= \int \frac{x^4+2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}. \sqrt{x^2-1} dx $$ 
How to solve this?

Comment: don't you $-1 \le x \le 1?$ how can the integrating factor $\sqrt{x^2 - 1}?$

Comment: May be worth writing the coefficient of y in the 1st line as $ \frac {-x}{1-x^2}  $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write $\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{xy}{x^2-1}= \frac{x^4+2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ as 
$$x^4 + 4x = \sqrt{1-x^2}\dfrac{dy}{dx}-\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}y= \dfrac{d(y\sqrt{1-x^2})}{dx}$$  which can be integrated to give

$$y\sqrt{1-x^2} = 
\dfrac{1}{5}x^5 +2x^2 + C. $$

Comment: Thanks,  exact differential it hard to see

Comment: @Tesla, you can always use the method called the variation of parameters.